# Can I use a resource (resx) file as an "Embedded Resource" *as well as* as "Content"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, resx, app-globalresources

I have a resx file in the App_GlobalResources folder of my ASP.NET web application.

- Its build property must be set to "Content", so that the file is automatically included during publishing and I can use `<%$ Resources: ... %>` expressions.
- Its build property must be set to "Embedded Resource", [so that my unit tests can access the resources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4153748/87698).

Is there some trick that I can use to have both?

---

Note: The solutions in the linked question won't work, since

- mocking HttpContext won't give the unit test access to non-embedded resources, and
- moving the resources out of App_GlobalResources breaks `<%$ Resources: ... %>` support after deployment.

Is there any solution that I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the build property of your resource files to "Embedded Resource".

Then, to ensure that they are included when publishing, add the following to the bottom of your `vbproj` or `csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="CopyResx" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResxFilesToCopy Include="App_GlobalResources\*.resx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ResxFilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\$(WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)\App_GlobalResources" />
</Target>
```

Note: We need to use `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage` instead of `MSDeployPublish`, since the latter [won't be executed when publishing a web application to a file system directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35556997/87698).